# Install different versions of requirements depending on the parent

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, requirements.txt

So, I have the following situation: suppose there is a python package used by many various projects, which has the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my-package',
    version='1.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'some-other-package==1.2.3',
    ],
    extras_require={
        'test': ['some-other-package==2.3.4'],
    }
)
```

In short, I want it to use version `1.2.3` of `some-other-package` in all cases except for when I specify the `[test]` extra (for this occasion I want to use `2.3.4`).

All works great when I use

```
my-package @ git+ssh://...
```

in `requirements.txt`, however, if I do

```
my-package[test] @ git+ssh://...
```

then I get the following error when trying to install requirements:

```
my-package 1.1.0 depends on some-other-package==1.2.3
my-package 1.1.0 depends on some-other-package==2.3.4
```

Can you please advise, is there a way around this? Maybe it is possible to pass the required version to `setup.py` in some other way through the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I know it is not what you asked for and probably also not what you want to read but, it is not a good idea to have pinned dependencies ("concrete dependencies") in `install_requires`: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/ -- So I guess what I would recommend is to move the strict version constraints from the packaging metadata (`install_requires` in `setup.py`) and into a `requirements.txt` or `constraints.txt` file instead.